# unable to read json file generated from gson library

Tags: javascript, json

This is part of javascript file I am using to read json file.

```
function initSearchInfo() {
    var tagContent = "";
    var tagsCount = 15;
    var i = 0;
    $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
        url : JSON_URL + SEARCH_HISTORY_JSON + EXT_JSON + versionParam,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data.count, function(key, val) {
                i++;
                if (i > tagsCount) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    tagContent += "<li><a data-weight=" + val + "     href='"
                        + GLOBAL_SEARCH_URL + key + "'>" + key
                        + "</a></li>";
            }
        });
        $("#taglist").html(tagContent);

    },
    error : function(xhr, status, error) {
        $("#tagCloud").html(getMessage(tagcloud.error));
        $("#searchHistory").hide();
        console.log(status);
    }
});
```

}

I am able to read this json file(1) :

```
{
    "count": {
        "scm": {
            "count": 22,
            "date": "2013-05-08"
        },
        "java7": {
            "count": 22,
            "date": "2013-05-08"
        },
        "groovy": {
            "count": 22,
            "date": "2013-05-08"
        },
        "ldap": {
            "count": 21,
            "date": "2013-04-25"
        }
    },
    "date": "10Oct2013"
}
```

But when I read this file (2):

```
{"count":"{\"ldap\":{\"count\":15,\"date\":\"2013-04-04\"},\"myplace\":{\"count\":12,\"date\":\"2013-05-08\"},\"ts-ws1\":{\"count\":11,\"date\":\"2013-05-08\"},\"hbase workshop\":{\"count\":11,\"date\":\"2013-05-08\"},"date":"11 Oct 2013"}
```

My code breaks when I try to read file (2).
File (2) is produced by gson library.But file (1) is written by me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is syntax error with the file giving error.
Value of "count" key is in double quotes and they don't end properly.

Answer (score 0):

file(2) is not a valid json file. You can't have a double quote before the second { and also you can't have backslash before the double quotes. Please post your code that generates file(2).

Comment: file 2 is a valid json file.

Comment: @akashmkr6 Why so? I found that it is not valid with this [validator](http://jsonlint.com/)